# woocommerce_free_price_html not working

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I used the following code to change the 0,00 to a text in Wordpress Woocommerce, but it doesn't work anymore:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_free_price_html', 'changeFreePriceNotice', 10, 2);

function changeFreePriceNotice($price, $product) {
    return 'Call for price';
}
```

Does anyone know how to solve this? Google can't help me unfortunately. Hope somebody can help me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Since WooCommerce 3.0 woocommerce_free_price_html does not work any more**

I could not find the information why it no longer works.

But I found one solution and adapted it, making it more universal:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html','custom_free_price_text' );

function custom_free_price_text( $product ) {
    global $product;
    $price = $product->get_price();

    if($price == '0.00') {
        return 'Call for price';
    } else {
        return "$ ".$price;
    }
}
```